# SQLLite time entry and time exit from eventime

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables, `DATA` and `EVENTS`, with the following data:

```
EVENTS
EventIndex  ObjID   LocID   EventData   EventTime       EventType
83707365    3519434 10376   0           2013-05-19 11:32:11 137
83707849    3519434 10374   0           2013-05-19 11:35:18 137 
83714233    888799  10376   0           2013-05-19 12:24:45 137 
83715200    888799  10184   0           2013-05-19 12:32:18 137

DATA
EventIndex  TagName TagValue    
83714233    ObjName Peter
83714233    LocName H118
83715200    ObjName Peter
83715200    LocName H116
83707365    ObjName John
83707365    LocName H118
83707849    ObjName John
83707849    LocName H116
```

Where do I start with a SQL SQLLite query?

I want to get the results:

```
Name   Location  Entry      Exit        Total
Peter  H118      12:24:45   12:32:18    00:07:33
John   H118      11:32:11   11:35:18    00:03:07
```

Hi meewoK, can give the following case:

Name     Location    Entry  Exit            Total
Peter    H118        12:24:45   12:32:18    00:07:33
John     H118        11:32:11   11:35:18    00:03:07
John     H118        11:44:52   11:45:27    00:00:35
John     H118        12:31:15   12:32:46    00:01:31

and I'm trying to modify your query and I can not find the solution. Thanks

This code works in SQL SERVER:

SELECT E.EventIndex,  N.tagvalue AS Name, L.tagvalue AS Location, E.eventtime AS Entry, NEV.[Exit]
FROM
    [EVENTS] E
    INNER JOIN [DATA] N ON E.EventIndex = N.eventindex AND N.tagname = 'ObjName'
    INNER JOIN [DATA] L ON E.EventIndex = L.eventindex AND L.tagname = 'LocName'
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1) NE.eventtime AS [Exit]
        FROM
            [EVENTS] NE
            INNER JOIN [DATA] NL ON NE.EventIndex = NL.eventindex AND   NL.tagname = 'ObjName'
        WHERE
            NE.EventIndex > E.EventIndex
            AND NL.tagvalue = N.tagvalue
        ORDER BY
            NE.EventIndex

```
) NEV
```

WHERE L.tagvalue = 'H118'

Someone could help me to pass it to SQLite?
Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between "Entry" and "Exit" records? There is no such information in the `EVENTS` table.

Comment: Hi CL, the difference is in the table DATA. The event 83714233 locates Peter in the H118 and event 83715200 locates Peter in H116, so we know that 83715200 is the output event, not if I have explained. Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS and version please? And is EventIndex ascending always?

Comment: Are you sure the eventType is the same all the time? Also, what happens if there are more than 2 events for a Person? Are these numbers per day?

Comment: So `H118` is `Entry`, `H116` is `Exit`, and anything else for the `LocName` tag can be ignored? Then why is there the `Location` column in the output?

Comment: No, in this case I'm looking for those who have been located in room H118

Comment: If the difference is not in the `Location` column, then what is it?

Comment: CL Sorry, my English is not very good. I want to know who has been in room H118 at a specific date and time

Comment: ...or any other location

Comment: Hi gbn, SQLLite and 3.7.16.2 version. Yes

Comment: Hi meewoK, sorry, my English is not very good. Is different but only interest me the eventType 137. If more than two events are in the location (LocName) I'm looking for (H118) must be displayed in the query. May be on a time interval.

Comment: Any other location, or one specific location?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714039/sql-time-entry-and-time-exit-from-eventime/ You shouldn't post the same question multiple times please.

Comment: Hi meewoK, sorry ... it was not on purpose. I did not know where he fit best the question

Comment: Hi CL, any other location

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick SQL dump for working on the table.

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTS (EventIndex int, objID int, eventtime datetime);
INSERT INTO "EVENTS" VALUES(83707365,3519434,'2013-05-19 11:32:11');
INSERT INTO "EVENTS" VALUES(83707849,3519434,'2013-05-19 11:35:18');
INSERT INTO "EVENTS" VALUES(83714233,888799,'2013-05-19 12:24:25');
INSERT INTO "EVENTS" VALUES(83714233,888799,'2013-05-19 12:32:18');
CREATE TABLE DATA (eventindex int, tagname char, tagvalue char);
INSERT INTO "DATA" VALUES(83714233,'ObjName','Peter');
INSERT INTO "DATA" VALUES(83714233,'LocName','H118');
INSERT INTO "DATA" VALUES(83715200,'ObjName','Peter');
INSERT INTO "DATA" VALUES(83715200,'LocName','H118');
INSERT INTO "DATA" VALUES(83707365,'ObjName','John');
INSERT INTO "DATA" VALUES(83707849,'ObjName','John');
INSERT INTO "DATA" VALUES(83707365,'LocName','H118');
INSERT INTO "DATA" VALUES(83707849,'LocName','H118');
```

Step 1, get the maximal and minimal `eventtype` for each `ObjID`:

```
SELECT ObjID, Min(EventIndex) as EventIndex, Min(EventTime) as Entry, Max(EventTime) as Exit
  FROM EVENTS GROUP BY ObjID;


ObjID    EventIndex     Entry      Exit
3519434   83707365   12:24:45  12:32:18
 888799   83714233   11:32:11  11:25:18
```

Now this reveals some problems with your data structure. For each `ObjID`, you have two `EventIndex`, so which one should you pick? Here, I have simply selected the first (smallest) of the two.

Step 2, because sqlite3 dislikes performing operations on aggregates, we make it into a view:

```
CREATE VIEW single_events AS 
SELECT ObjID, Min(EventIndex) as EventIndex, Min(EventTime) as Entry, Max(EventTime) as Exit FROM EVENTS GROUP BY ObjID;
```

Step 3, get the total time by operating on the view:

```
SELECT *, time(strftime('%s', exit) - strftime('%s', entry), 'unixepoch') as total 
  FROM single_events;
ObjID       EventIndex  Entry                Exit                 total
----------  ----------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------
888799      83714233    2013-05-19 12:24:25  2013-05-19 12:32:18  00:07:53
3519434     83707365    2013-05-19 11:32:11  2013-05-19 11:35:18  00:03:07
```

Step 4, merge this with `DATA`.

```
SELECT d1.TagValue as Name, d2.TagValue as Location, Entry, Exit, time(strftime('%s', exit) - strftime('%s', entry), 'unixepoch') as total
  FROM single_events
  LEFT JOIN DATA as d1 USING (EventIndex)
  LEFT JOIN DATA as d2 USING (EventIndex)
  WHERE d1.tagname = 'ObjName' AND d2.tagname = 'LocName';
```

Of course, if it is a very large data set, you might benefit from pouring `d1` and `d2` into a temporary table before running step 4.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could get you started along nicely:

**SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e6a7/33**

```
SELECT d.TagValue AS Name,
       d2.TagValue AS LOCATION,
       e.eventTime AS Entry,

  ( SELECT eventtime
   FROM EVENTS e2
   WHERE e2.objID = e.objID
     AND e2.eventTime > e.eventTime LIMIT 1) AS ExitTime,
       (e.eventTime -
          ( SELECT eventtime
           FROM EVENTS e2
           WHERE e2.objID = e.objID
             AND e2.eventTime > e.eventTime LIMIT 1)) AS TotalTime
FROM events e,
     DATA d,
          DATA d2
WHERE e.eventIndex = d.eventIndex
  AND e.eventIndex = d2.eventIndex
  AND d.TagName = "ObjName"
  AND d2.TagName = "LocName"
  AND mod(
            ( SELECT count(*)
             FROM EVENTS e2
             WHERE e2.objID = e.objID
               AND e2.eventTime < e.eventTime),2) = 0
ORDER BY EventTime;
```

Result:

```
NAME    LOCATION    ENTRY                   EXITTIME                  TOTALTIME
John    H118    May, 19 2013 11:32:11+0000  May, 19 2013 11:35:18+0000  -307
Peter   H118    May, 19 2013 12:24:45+0000  May, 19 2013 12:32:18+0000  -773
```

I added extra events, to proof against an exit from one event being considered as an entry of another.

The above query can be optimized, if we say that an entry and exit cannot take place on different days e.g. USER enters 11.59PM and leaves 1.00AM...

```
SELECT d.TagValue AS Name,
       d2.TagValue AS LOCATION,
       e.eventTime AS Entry,

  ( SELECT eventtime
   FROM EVENTS e2
   WHERE e2.objID = e.objID
     AND e2.eventTime > e.eventTime LIMIT 1) AS ExitTime,
       (e.eventTime -
          ( SELECT eventtime
           FROM EVENTS e2
           WHERE e2.objID = e.objID
             AND e2.eventTime > e.eventTime AND
             DATE(e2.eventTime) = DATE(e.eventTime) LIMIT 1)) AS TotalTime
FROM events e,
     DATA d,
          DATA d2
WHERE e.eventIndex = d.eventIndex
  AND e.eventIndex = d2.eventIndex
  AND d.TagName = "ObjName"
  AND d2.TagName = "LocName"
  AND mod(
            ( SELECT count(*)
             FROM EVENTS e2
             WHERE e2.objID = e.objID
               AND e2.eventTime < e.eventTime AND
               DATE(e2.eventTime) = DATE(e.eventTime)),2) = 0
ORDER BY EventTime;
```

**SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e6a7/35**

This also assumes that each `entry` must have an `exit`, which is why I use the modulo operator. 
All `Even` events for a `Object` are an entry, all `Odd` events are an `exit`.

For more conditions, obviously the query must be modified.

**Update: Using SQL Lite (no mod but %)**

**SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6e6a7/4**

```
SELECT d.TagValue AS Name,
       d2.TagValue AS LOCATION,
       e.eventTime AS Entry,

  ( SELECT eventtime
   FROM EVENTS e2
   WHERE e2.objID = e.objID
     AND e2.eventTime > e.eventTime LIMIT 1) AS ExitTime,
       (e.eventTime -
          ( SELECT eventtime
           FROM EVENTS e2
           WHERE e2.objID = e.objID
             AND e2.eventTime > e.eventTime LIMIT 1)) AS TotalTime
FROM events e,
     DATA d,
          DATA d2
WHERE e.eventIndex = d.eventIndex
  AND e.eventIndex = d2.eventIndex
  AND d.TagName = "ObjName"
  AND d2.TagName = "LocName"
  AND (
            ( SELECT count(*)
             FROM EVENTS e2
             WHERE e2.objID = e.objID
               AND e2.eventTime < e.eventTime)%2) = 0
ORDER BY EventTime;
```

Comment: Hi meewoK, Thanks. Does a Visit consist of finding an entry and an exit? I need to find people who have been in a location (H118) in a range of dates.
How far apart can these two be? Anyone.
What happens between hits that are a day apart? Present them in the query

Comment: Well, the first query works across dates. Basically, any hit on one reader must be followed by another hit at anothe reader later. Problems arise if someone hits their card multiple times in a row... you need more complicated logic for that. BTW this reminds me of an RFID I have seen before. Are you be any chance using a software system called centaur which logs events in an MS SQL from controllers connected to rfid readers? just curious...

Comment: Oh...and if you don't care about the exit time and only entry times on a specific query, the logic becomes much easier...

Comment: SQLite3 does not - per default - support the `mod`-function. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Comment: @ MrGumble, yes this is from the merged question which did not mention SQLLite. In any case, I see SQLLite supports `%` which is the same thing. http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/expressions/ Under arithmetic. I have updated the code and have an updated fiddle using sqlLite: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6e6a7/4 :)

Comment: Hi meewoK, your query works fine but does not work when a person is located by the same antenna on several occasions. I've put an example up. I tried modifying your query but I can not find the solution. Thanks

Comment: @user1250864 Yeh, one solution would be to ignore all consecutive later hits so only check one. Another requirement could be to wait X number of minutes before counting a hit. Is there any chance an enter and exit will happen from the same reader?

Comment: Yes. Name    Location Entry      Exit       Total
     Peter    H118    12:24:45   12:32:18   00:07:33
     John     H118    11:32:11   11:35:18   00:03:07
     John     H118    11:44:52   11:45:27   00:00:35
     John     H118    12:31:15    12:32:46  00:01:31

Comment: Well..what is going to be the condition to classify 2 events as Separate? Time difference? If someone goes to close to the antenaa and you have 2 hits in 1 minute? :)

Comment: System way work is that it locate a tag only when this change of antenna. Each event is refered to this change. There are not minimun time between location in same antenna. For example, Antenna1 locate Tag1, 1 hour later, Antenna2 locate Tag1 and 1second later Antenna1 locate Tag1. Each change of location is a event, the time between it is only determined for Tag movement