# SQL time entry and time exit from eventime

Tags: sql

I have two tables, DATA and EVENTS, with the following data:

```
EVENTS
EventIndex  ObjID   LocID   EventData   EventTime       EventType
83707365    3519434 10376   0           2013-05-19 11:32:11 137
83707849    3519434 10374   0           2013-05-19 11:35:18 137 
83714233    888799  10376   0           2013-05-19 12:24:45 137 
83715200    888799  10184   0           2013-05-19 12:32:18 137

DATA
EventIndex  TagName TagValue    
83714233    ObjName Peter
83714233    LocName H118
83715200    ObjName Peter
83715200    LocName H116
83707365    ObjName John
83707365    LocName H118
83707849    ObjName John
83707849    LocName H116
```

Where do I start with a SQL query?

I want to get the results:

```
Name   Location  Entry      Exit        Total
Peter  H118      12:24:45   12:32:18    00:07:33
John   H118      11:32:11   11:35:18    00:03:07
```

The event 83714233 locates Peter in the H118 and event 83715200 locates Peter in H116, so we know that 83715200 is the output event, not if I have explained

Thanks